# iOS MvxTableViewController Custom Cell : How to bind UIView's position?

Tags: data-binding, uiimageview, mvvmcross, xib, custom-cell

I use a MvxTableViewController with custom cells within MvxTableViewCell  and xib file to display a list of blog post. Each blog post can contains 1 to 3 items of differents type (Picture, Text and Sound).
I added 3 UIImageView. These 3 ImageView appear depending on contents of the blog post. I would like to know what’s the best way to do this with MVVMCross. How can i bind ViewModel property to UIImageView's position ?

The link below represented the desired result :

http://s25.postimg.org/li38jzdsf/Screen.png

Comment: What did google say, and the rest of stackoverflow?

Comment: Maybe you should think about it differently and simple show/hide the 3 views depending on properties in your ViewModel.

Comment: You can bind position or size properties using value converters if you want to. Another option would be to use constraints for alignment and then just set the widths to control visibility